# select columns based on criteria in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a df with many columns. I want to only use the columns where the latest observation is less than the maximum observation.

I have tried some variations of the following, but there must be something I am missing:

```
df = df[[i for i in df.columns if df.iloc[:,-1] < df[i].max()]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following? 
This should work just fine

```
for i in df.columns:
         if df.iloc[:,-1] < df[i].max():

              #Do something here..
```

Comment: How do I move from there to a df with only the columns matching my criteria?

Comment: Just create a new column in the dataframe and insert the values to the column if they match the criteria in the nested if statement in the for loop